# how to use maps in an offline power bi dashboard, it can be created online then transferred to the offline machine?

Tags: powerbi, visualization, powerbi-desktop, dashboard, geo

I want to show a map of regions, or the main cities of Saudi Arabia then map some information to it,
at the end the map should show in an offline machine, but I can develop it in a machine with online connection then transfer it their if it's an option.

I tried using the regular map visuals then saving the file and opening it again offline but it didn't work